How to fill an nd array with values from a 1d-array?
The following is a real-world problem in numPy reduced to the essentials, just with smaller dimensions.
Let's say I want to create an n-dimensional array all with dimensions (10, 10, 100):
all = np.empty((10, 10, 100))

I also have a 1d array data, simulated here as
data = np.arange(0, 100) 

for all i, j I now want to achieve that
all[i,j]=data

So I do:
all[:, :]=data

Of course that works.
But now I want to import data to all2 with shape (100, 10, 10). I could do that with
all2 = np.empty((100, 10, 10)) # new target to be populated
for i in range(100):
  for j in range(10):
    for k in range(10):
      all2[i, j, k]=data[i]

But is there an easier way to do this without looping? I would be surprised if it couldn't be done more elegantly, but I don't see how.

I'm not big on NumPy but you should have a look into the reshape functions, this may help!

all2[:] = data[:, None,None].  This puts a (100, 1,1) shape into the (100,10,10).

You can use transpose: all2.T[:] = data (note the second , : insn't necessary)

most easy.
I would never have thought of that

You can also define directly  all = np.tile(data, (10,10,1)) and  all2 = np.tile(data, (10,10,1)).T although using all as variable name is a terrible idea...

as I told - this is only a boiled-down version of my original problem

I would have written all2.T[:,:] = data  - why is the second : not required?

@MichaelW: NumPy automatically fills in as many trailing :s as necessary.

Assignment to the transposed view is faster than the tile (or repeat) approach.  But what about all3 with a (10,100,10) shape?
